# How to rewrite dynamic URL to SEO Friendly URL?

Tags: php, apache

I tried everything I see here in this site to rewrite dynamic url to SEO friendly URL.

Is it maybe because im using it in the localhost?

I try this but does not work also:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php/?([^ ]*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?(.*) /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond $0 !^index\.php($|/)
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```

I also refer to an online dynamic url generator , but it doesn't work either. Please help.

I would like to rewrite these couple of URLs:

```
index.php?p=home
index.php?p=about me
index.php?p=contact me
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this one:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

 # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1
```

Then on your index.php page, all the variables will put accessible via $_GET['q']. If you further use $location=array_filter(explode('/',$_GET['q'])); then $location will be an array containing each directory, so www.mysite.com/firstdir/seconddir/thirddir will have $location[0] as 'firstdir' and $location[1] as 'seconddir' and so on. You could then compare these to url_aliases in your database to determine what content/template to display.

This also works for localhost for me, except I change the base url part from "/" to "/mycurrentconstructionsite/"

Hope that helps!

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: are you copy pasting it exactly as that? make sure you keep the / if you are in the root directory or user "/mydirectory/" if you want a different directory... if you are using localhost/mytestsite (ex. via xampp) then do `code`RewriteBase /mytestsite/`code` with the rest staying the same

Comment: yes sir, and actually I put the .htaccess file inside my DynamiWebsite folder together all the web files.